# Improve string.Format CallExpression

Tags: c#, expression-trees, dynamic-language-runtime

I am trying to call `string.Format` using Tree

It took me a bit of work since my supply `params Expression[] _ParameterExpressions` does not match signature of `string.Format` which accept `object[]` it seems it won't apply implicit conversion.

My current solution is to convert my supplied parameter into `object[]` using

```
NewArrayExpression _NewArray = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), _ParameterExpressions.Select(ep => Expression.Convert(ep, typeof(object))));
```

and setup my proxy function to pass parameters to `string.Format` (I need this or else it would say it could not find matched signature)

```
static string ReplaceParameters(string format, params object[] obj)
{
    return string.Format(format, obj);
}

static IEnumerable<Expression> ReplaceStringExpression(Expression exp)
{
    yield return exp;
    yield return _NewArray;
}
```

And finally my call

```
ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(orginalString, typeof(string));
MethodCallExpression me = Expression.Call(typeof(RuleParser), "ReplaceParameters", null,
                ReplaceStringExpression(ce).ToArray());
```

The expression works but I don't really like the idea of creating new array which includes extra boxing process. I think it was overdone on such simple function call.

How can I improve this `string.Format` call?

==========

**Edit**

Have some progress on my study. I can now ditch `ReplaceParameters` but still don't like to create array of object `_NewArray`

```
MethodCallExpression me = Expression.Call(
     typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", new Type[2] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) }),
     ReplaceStringExpression(ce).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When ExpressionTree is created by the compiler - it will contain all implicit required conversions to make selected method overload work

   ```
   Expression<Func<string>> compilerFactoredExpressionTree = () => string.Format("{0} and {1} and {2} and {3}", 1, "text", true, 2);
   // test
   // "1 and text and True and 2"
   string s = compilerFactoredExpressionTree.Compile()();
   // ArrayInit(Convert(1), Convert("text", Convert(2)))
   Expression methodArgs = ((MethodCallExpression)compilerFactoredExpressionTree.Body).Arguments[1];
   ```
2. If you construct ExpressionTree manually - you'll need to act as compiler yourself - insert conversions by hand or initially declare values with required type

   ```
   var parameters = new Expression[]
   {
       Expression.Constant(1, typeof(object)),
       Expression.Constant("text", typeof(object)),
       Expression.Constant(true, typeof(object)),
       Expression.Constant(2, typeof(object)),
   };

   var mi = new Func<string, object[], string>(string.Format).Method;

   var callStringFormat = Expression.Call(mi, Expression.Constant("{0} and {1} and {2} and {3}"), Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), parameters));

   // "1 and text and True and 2"
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(callStringFormat);
   var r = lambda.Compile()();
   ```